# How do you set the results_directory in SST Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm feeling a bit foolish asking this, as with basic selenium I have no problem saving screenshots, yet with SST I use the `take_screenshot('screenshot_name.png')` it tells me that the results_directory should be set. Question is how do you set the results_directory. All of the examples I find set it to "NONE", yet that doesn't satisfy my test's need.

Below is how my code is written:

```
import unittest
from sst.actions import *
from sst import cases, config

config.results_directory = None

class TestMyTest(cases.SSTTestCase):

def test_mytestcase_home_page(self):
    go_to('http://www.mywebpage.com')
    assert_title_contains('MyWebPage')
    #Main page is displayed
    take_screenshot(filename='C/Users/Brenda/test/SST Test Project/results/home_page.png',add_timestamp=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried with passing full file name such as `take_screenshot(filename='directory/screenshot.png', add_timestamp=True)`

Comment: I did, and it still gives the MismatchError: None matches Is(None): results_directory should be set.

Comment: Not sure how you are executing the tests. But [API](http://testutils.org/sst/index.html#example-sst-test-script) says with commandline option `-s` should automatically save screenshot and **you might have to modify the config file and add result directory which is empty now**. You can run `from sst import config`to see you config setting

Comment: I'm running the test in PyCharm.

Comment: I've added the code I have in the OP.

Comment: `config.results_directory = None` is (may be)killing it. set the result directory `config.results_directory = C/Users/Brenda/test/SST Test Project/results/` and have `take_screenshot(filename='home_page.png',add_timestamp=True)` and try

Comment: I changed it to: config.results_directory = 'C/Users/Brenda/test/SST Test Project/results/' with the same error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65638/discussion-between-saifur-and-brenda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the following script working for me using Google. The trick was to add result directory to actual config file which is located @{dir}\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sst\config.py and add `results_directory = "C:\Users\{me}\Desktop\Python-pip-SST\results"`

```
import unittest
from sst.actions import *
from sst import cases, config

#config.results_directory = "C:\Users\{me}\Desktop\Python-pip-SST\results"

go_to('https://www.google.com/')
assert_title_contains('Google')
#Main page is displayed
take_screenshot(filename='home_page.png',add_timestamp=True)
```

And, You also should be able to overwrite the result path from your test. Your working code should look like something like the following

```
import unittest
from sst.actions import *
from sst import cases, config

#Just to be safe side try not to use any spaces in filename
config.results_directory = "C:/Users/Brenda/test/SSTTestProject/results"

class TestMyTest(cases.SSTTestCase):

def test_mytestcase_home_page(self):
    go_to('http://www.mywebpage.com')
    assert_title_contains('MyWebPage')
    #Main page is displayed
    take_screenshot(filename="home_page.png",add_timestamp=True)
```

I added the screenshot if that helps you somehow. Changing filepath innconfig file or from test works fine for me
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I updated my config file with the correct path, then executed the test. It still gives me the same mistmatch error message.

Comment: Just did, and it runs clean, but no screenshot.

Comment: Mine stops the browser before it gets to the screenshot.

Comment: I assume your filepath is correct. Because in original post I see you missed `:` after `C` and, also watch the `/` slashes. Additionally, you also can try `take_screenshot('home_page.png',True)` without filename which should work as well. If it doesn't then I think it has something to do with `sst` or `python` version. I have the latest

Comment: I have entered config.results_directory = "C:/Users/Brenda/test/SST-Test-Project/results" for the config file

Comment: This is really getting to me. It works for the google, but not for my webpage. Yet the code is almost identical.

Comment: I would suggest you to give it try without using `class ` and execute form `cmd` from to see what's the difference

Comment: That seemed to correct this issue. I wonder why it won't work when classes are defined?